# My passport doesn't carry my occupation. Will this affect me at my visa interview

Tags: visas, international-travel

My passport doesn't carry my occupation. I am a Cameroonian citizen and in our passports, there's a place for occupation. Is this going to affect my American dv lottery visa interview?

Comment: Hmmm.. are there passports in the world that have the holder's occupation? What makes you think it could be a problem?

Comment: The USA passport does not contain occupation. The Chinese passport does.

Comment: @Michael Occupation/profession is not listed as one of th details in the Chinese passport. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_passport#Format

Comment: @Neusser They must have changed it. It used to: https://www.visarite.com/chinesepassportsample.htm. On the first picture, there's a field for "Profession".

Comment: @Neusser Here's a better picture: http://www.clearharmony.net/a_images/2004/07/orig/2004-07-22-2004-7-15-passport-2-orig.jpg

Comment: Old joke "**British Border Officer** *Country of origin?* **Traveler** *Russia!* **British Border Officer** *Occupation?* *No, no! Just visiting.* Obs:. You can swamp countries depending of your audience, (country with petrol reserves) and USA for example.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you look at the [ICAO requirements](https://www.icao.int/publications/Documents/9303_p3_cons_en.pdf) for a passport, you will find no such field required. It's rare for a country to list occupation in the passport.

If you have a valid and legal passport, there should be no problem.

[image: ICAO Machine Readable Passports]

Comment: Yay someone used the official source to answer this question!

Comment: I really like that they used "Utopian" as the nationality in the example.

Comment: Is that Skyler White?

Comment: Why are passport standards under ICAO jurisdiction? Are they somehow tied to air travel?

Comment: @Mehrdad Yes, one generally uses a passport as a travel document.

Comment: @Sneftel: I don't think you understood my question.

Comment: The ICAO is working on Machine Readable passports. The member countries (190 of 193 UN members) have setup their passports to be compatible with the standards that they are setting. See https://www.icao.int/Security/FAL/TRIP/Pages/default.aspx for details. ICAO doesn't have "jurisdiction" over passports, but it is working on details that most countries of the world will implement domestically to be compatible with the rest of the world. I expect the ICAO is doing it because the global airline network has the greatest demand for this.

Comment: ICAO has jurisdiction over passports and related travel documents under [Annex 9 to the Chicago Convention](https://www.icao.int/Meetings/mrtd-madrid-2014/Documents/7_Slavenas-Annex-9.pdf).